# iOS app's cookies get wiped out when terminated. How to prevent this, or persist this cookie?

Tags: ios, session-cookies

I'm sending http requests with session-cookie stored on the device side. The problem is that I want  to persist it across app termination. But it seems like all the cookies of my app get deleted. I tried on both the simulator and device and they got the same behavior.

Is there any iOS way to prevent this cookie deletion? If not, how can I save it to disk and recover it back?

I'm planning to save this cookie in iOS keychain for security. And I think all NSHTTPCookie properties can be safely converted to NSString. So my current idea is to convert from **NSHTTPCookie -> NSDictionary -> String -> Save in Keychain**, and go backward to use get the original cookie. The problem is I don't want to go through the hassles of converting **NSDictionary -> String** and parsing **String -> NSDictionary**.

Comment: You could save and send the cookies yourself.

Comment: Yes, but does iOS provide this mechanism?

Comment: Kinda. If you've got a NSHTTPURLResponse, you can get an NSArray of NSHTTPCookies with NSHTTPCookie's +cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:forURL: method. Then to send them, you just gotta create the Cookie: header yourself. I'll post more details in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**===== SUMMARY =====**

Well, I'm going to create another answer just to summarize possible ways to persist a NSDictionary (that doesn't contain objects of course!).

The easiest way to do this is to use NSDictionary's `writeToFile:` method. This will generate a plist file. (Also available in NSArray) If you're worried about security, encrypt the array to an NSData object and write that.

Another way, not the fastest one though, is to use a tool to convert NSDictionary to a string format such as JSON or XML. You can save this string in iOS keychain and retrieve it later easily. (`SFHFKeychainUtils` is a great for helping with keychain stuff). A good thing about using keychain is it is automatically encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Found a nice clean way of doing this. The trick is using `JSONKit` (which came with RestKit) to convert between NSString and NSDictionary using JSON format. And here I use `SFHFKeychainUtils` to help me with the keychain stuff. This way you don't have to worry about each property in the cookie and all the conversion work. :)

```
#import "RestKit/JSONKit.h"

#define WSC_serviceName @"WSC_serviceName"
#define WSC_username    @"WSC_username"
#define WSC_cookieName  @"_your_cookie_name" // name of the session cookie

- (void)saveSessionCookieToKeyChain {
    for (NSHTTPCookie *c in [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookies) {
        if ([c.name isEqualToString:WSC_cookieName]) {
            NSString *cookieString = [c.properties JSONString];
            NSLog(@"cookieString: %@",cookieString);
            NSError *saveError = nil;
            [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:WSC_username
                                 andPassword:cookieString 
                              forServiceName:WSC_serviceName 
                              updateExisting:YES error:&saveError];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)readsSessionCookieFromKeyChain {
    NSError *readError = nil;
    NSString *jsonString = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:WSC_username
                                                      andServiceName:WSC_serviceName 
                                                               error:&readError];
    if (!jsonString) return NO;
    NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // be sure that data is in UTF8 or it won't work
    JSONDecoder* decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
    NSDictionary* jsonDict = (NSDictionary*)[decoder objectWithData:jsonData];
    NSLog(@"jsonDict: %@",jsonDict);

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [[NSHTTPCookie alloc] initWithProperties:jsonDict];
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];

    return cookie!=nil;
}

- (void)clearSessionCookieAndRemoveFromKeyChain {
    for (NSHTTPCookie *c in [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookies) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:c];
    }
    NSError *deleteError = nil;
    [SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:WSC_username 
                              andServiceName:WSC_serviceName 
                                       error:&deleteError];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an NSHTTPURLResponse, you can get an array of cookies like so:

```
NSDictionary * headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
NSArray * cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:headers forURL:response.URL];
```

Where `response` is the NSHTTPURLResponse.

You're going to get NSURLResponses in these 2 methods of the NSURLConnectionDelegate

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```

NSHTTPCookie has a `properties` property which returns an `NSDictionary`, so you can save them.
They can then be created with the same dictionary using `-initWithProperties:`

To send them, you'll need to create your own string for the Cookie header of a `NSURLRequest`.
Something like:

```
NSMutableString * cookieString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSHTTPCookie * cookie in myLoadedCookies){
    [cookieString appendFormat:@"%@=%@; ", cookie.name, cookie.value];
}
[request setValue:cookieString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
[cookieString release];
```

Where `request` is an `NSMutableURLRequest`.

You should also make sure to stop iOS managing cookies itself:

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Comment: I'm using Restkit to send and receive requests so I'm not directly dealing with NSURLRequest myself. The way I get the cookie is `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookies`, which in my case will work just the same as your code. The problem is how do I save that NSHTTPCookie to the disk. I'm kind of finding a better way than to iterate through each NSDictionary entry and produce one long string that I can save to iOS keychain (for security), and then parse that string back to NSDictionary again to recover the cookie. I don't want to go through that parsing hassles :(

Comment: There's no sense parsing if you can save an NSArray of NSDictionarys. NSArray has a writeToFile method, and an initWithContentsOfFile you can use. If you're worried about security, encrypt the array to an NSData object and write that.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know there is a `writeToFile:` method for those collection classes.